# Google indexing api urlNotifications/metadata returns 404 error

Tags: api, google-search, google-indexing-api

I am trying to check if my website page have been indexed by google. For this reason I am using Indexing API.  For this reason I intent to call urlNotifications/metadata ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/apis/indexing-api/v3/using-api)) to recieve metadata.

I am using php Google_api library for PHP. To set everything up I am using [this docs](https://developers.google.com/search/apis/indexing-api/v3/prereqs#create-project) to authorize and connect library.
I created Application -> enable Index API -> created service account-> added permission from website to service account -> created APP credentials(json file).
And used this cridentials to authorize client.

```
    require_once GOOGLE_API_PATH;

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig(GOOGLE_API_CREDENTIALS);
    $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing');
    $httpClient = $client->authorize();

    $json = array();
    $json['test'] = 'test';

    $json['credits'] = GOOGLE_API_CREDENTIALS;

    $endpoint = 'https://indexing.googleapis.com/v3/urlNotifications/metadata';

    $response = $httpClient->get($endpoint,[
            'query'=>['url' => 'https://bulbul.ua']
        ]);
    
    //output debug data
    $json['url'] = $endpoint;
    
    $status_code = $response->getStatusCode();
    $json['resp'] = $response->getStatusCode();
    $json['msg'] = $response->getReasonPhrase();
    $json['message'] = $response->getBody();

    $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
```

And the output is

> {"test":"test","credits":"hidden:)","url":"https://indexing.googleapis.com/v3/urlNotifications/metadata","resp":404,"msg":"Not Found","message":{}}

Looks like I am recieving 404  error. heres a [docs](https://developers.google.com/search/apis/indexing-api/v3/core-errors#NOT_FOUND) regarding this 404 error.

I know for sure that my website is indexed, especially this page.

Can someone help me with this issue?

I'm lost like Little Red Riding Hood  In the forest of GoogleApi Settings.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You need to set the read permission of gsc

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).